# Brokers and Negative Balance Protection

Tags: broker, leverage

I'm a bit confused about the Negative Balance Protection offered by many brokers, specially when they allow leverage, and a lot of leverage (common in brokers with CFDs).

How are they protecting against the losses?

For example, if I buy Apple using 10X leverage, and the gap (open market) at the next day is 15% negative, Who is paying the extra 5% of that loss?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I can offer an analogy that may or may not apply.  Some insurance companies offer Structured Annuity products that protect you from the first 10% of loss (and sometimes as much as 100%).  This protection is achieved via long puts and sometimes via various combinations of put and calls.